# Shortening Repetitive Code using Switch Case

Tags: c

Is there some way to convert this code into 5 lines, it seems quite repetitive.

I want to use switch case. Also, I would like to keep it at a beginner level.

```
void SortProductList(Product *productList, int size, char sortOption){
    Product temp;

    for (int i=0; i<size-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<size; j++)
        {
            if (sortOption == 'p') //sorting by price
            {
                if (productList[j].productPrice<productList[i].productPrice) //second is bigger than first
                {
                    temp = productList[i];
                    productList[i] = productList[j];
                    productList[j]=temp;
                }
            }
            if (sortOption == 'w') //sorting by weight
            {
                if (productList[j].productWeight<productList[i].productWeight) //second is bigger than first
                {
                    temp = productList[i];
                    productList[i] = productList[j];
                    productList[j]=temp;
                }
            }
            if (sortOption == 'n') //sorting by weight
            {
                if (strcmp(productList[j].productName,productList[i].productName)<0) //second is bigger than first
                {
                    temp = productList[i];
                    productList[i] = productList[j];
                    productList[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know about switch case, but it seems that application of `&&` and `||` could really help here. The repeated swapping code would then occur only once.

Comment: Offline, I thought about my comment above (which is also reflected by the answer below). I want to point out, that the construct only is equivalent because of the impossibility that two or more `if`s in OPs code can trigger. This is because otherwise OPs code could trigger two or more `then`s, but the `&&||` code cannot. So, in this special case the codes are equivalent, but only because it is a special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch statements don't seem to get you much further than you already are, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++){
            if ((sortOption == 'p' && productList[j].productPrice < productList[i].productPrice) ||
                (sortOption == 'w' && productList[j].productWeight < productList[i].productWeight) ||
                (sortOption == 'n' && (strcmp(productList[j].productName, productList[i].productName) < 0))){
                     temp = productList[i];
                     productList[i] = productList[j];
                     productList[j] = temp;
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh Nobody asked for better. Also, I disagree, I find this more efficiently to understand (thoug that might be a matter of taste). It definitly is better maintainable for the reduced number of repeated code alone. Horizontal scrolling is slightly annoying, it could be avoided by strategic use of newlines and indentation, another question of taste.